# How to use video html5 tag with onsen-ui and and javascript get this video tag

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, onsen-ui

In the following `onsen-ui` code, how can I select `video` object in the `<ons-page>` tag?

```
<script type="text/ons-template" id="play.html">
    <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar class="nav">
            <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="fa-bars"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
            <div class="center">Play</div>
        </ons-toolbar>

        <div id="play_div">

            <video style="max-width:700px; max-height:100%" id="video_player">
                <source src="audio/He_Cuoi.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </video>

        </div>
    </ons-page>
</script>
```

I've tried the following code.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("video_player");
    console.log(vid);
```

But `vid` returns `null`.

Comment: Onsen UI has nothing to do with that. Actually I can get the video with `document.getElementById("video_player")`. Are you trying it in Codepen?

Comment: it's worked when i try onsen ready

ons.ready(function(){ var vid = document.getElementById("video_player"); });

Comment: Oh, I was trying it in JavaScript console after everything was loaded. So yes, you just need to wait until everything is loaded to access the elements.